# Push Jar file instead of Zip using maven nexus

Tags: maven, maven-3, nexus, nexus3

I am trying to push zip file using `mvn deploy` command. The command I am using is:

```
mvn clean -s settings.xml \
      package deploy:deploy-file \
      -Dfile=${ARTIFACT_ID}-${VERSION}.zip \
      -Durl=${NEXUSURL}/repository/maven-${PKGREPO} \
      -DrepositoryId=nexus-${PKGREPO} -DpomFile=pom.xml \
      -DskipTests -Dpitest.execution.skip=true -Ddependency-check.skip=true
```

but I can find .jar file instead of zip?

Comment: First why trying to deploy via deploy-file and not as part of `mvn deploy`?

Comment: I am adding some files to the zip also .

Comment: able to resolve after adding Dpackage=zip

Comment: Better is to attach the maven-assembly-plugin to the life cycle and use only `mvn deploy` instead... that will handle that in one go...

Answer (score 1):

Able to resolve after adding `-Dpackage=zip`.